# Remove Index.php from URL in PHP CodeIgniter in Fedora 16 server

Tags: php, codeigniter, fedora16

My web application doesn't work without index.php in URL. It has been working in my previous Laptop (OS: Ubuntu 10.10). In my new laptop, in OS Fedora 16 it doesn't work. I did all the checking like .htaccess, cofig.php etc. Other application rather than CodeIgniter framework like PHPMyAdmin, work fine. Following is my .htaccess code.

```
# Options
  Options -Multiviews
  Options +FollowSymLinks

 #Enable mod rewrite
 RewriteEngine On
 #the location of the root of your site
#if writing for subdirectories, you would enter /subdirectory
RewriteBase /barj

#Removes access to CodeIgniter system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css
#folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

in the config.php, I have the following conf

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['REQUEST_URI']  = "AUTO";
```

Please give me any idea to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please check in appache configuration file that mod_rewrite module is enable or not.

You can check it by following command.

```
echo phpinfo();
```

If it is not enabled, enable it.

Comment: it is enabled. in phpinfo(), mod_rewrite shows in loaded modules under apache2handler configuration. any more idea?

Comment: First please tryout this minimal code and check it. It is working fine for me: # Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Comment: Why post two answers to the same question?

Answer (score 0):

First try out this minimal code. It is working fine for me.

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I put it to the .htaccess file after removing all the code in it. but still it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks a lot for your response.